# i get access forbidden from Apache (httpd) in fedora 34, Laravel, SELinux

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, fedora, httpd.conf, selinux

I have configured httpd in my fedora and I checked everything is true but i get

> access forbidden

I have tested everything about .htaccess but still getting access forbidden. also, my laravel folder permissions are correct.
I tested a sample project while installing httpd it worked perfectly with no 'access forbidden' message.

---

this is my httpd config

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName  test.com
    ServerAlias www.test.com
    DocumentRoot /home/myuser/gitlab/register/public
    <Directory /home/myuser/gitlab/register/public>
         DirectoryIndex index.php
         AllowOverride All
         Require all granted
         Order allow,deny
         Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

this is my htaccess in laravel public folder

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? How is this related to Fedora, or Laravel itself?

Comment: I do the same configs on ubuntu and it works with no problems but in fedora, i get the` access forbidden`. in some situations .htaccess in laravel project may cause problems like this I have tested solutions about the laravel .htaccess and i am sure the laravel project and its folder permissions is not the case

Comment: Then there must be some difference. What have you tried to find it? Like: does the error log contain any message? Are the permissions set appropriately? Do the folders exist?

Comment: yes the folder permissions are correct

Answer (score 0):

your probably creating the issue by mixing old Apache syntax with new Apache syntax, modern versions of Apache should be something like this...

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName  test.com
    ServerAlias www.test.com
    DocumentRoot /home/myuser/gitlab/register/public
    <Directory /home/myuser/gitlab/register/public>
         DirectoryIndex index.php
         AllowOverride All
         Require all granted
         # Order allow,deny
         # Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: thanks for the help I have tried this but still, the problem exists @MikeMoy

Answer (score 0):

> I found the problem.

it is because of the

> SELinux

ubuntu does not uses SELinux by default but RedHat distributions use it by default. SELinux prevents apache to access the home directory for the sake of security so if you disable or put it to Permissive mode, apache can access your home directory to load the web project. if you do not want to disable SELinux so **the correct location for web applications is in */var/www/* folder**
so if we change httpd config to

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName  test.com
    ServerAlias www.test.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/gitlab/register/public
    <Directory /var/www/gitlab/register/public>
         DirectoryIndex index.php
         AllowOverride All
         Require all granted
         Order allow,deny
         Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

it works fine

Comment: there is no such thing as "correct location for web applications", apache can server web application from any folder of your choosing once configured correctly